# IIS installing features

Tags: iis

I keep getting this error when trying to install features on iss windows 2012. This happened when trying to copy iis application.config from one machine to another. Can i get a new copy of this file perhaps to resolve this issue. I have tried installing and reinstalling but no joy

[image]

Comment: I believe error `0x800f0922` is something along the lines of "permission denied". this could be anything from user not having rights (less likely) to it trying to access a file that's currently in use, such as an IIS config file. try stopping the IIS services.

Comment: have stopped the iis services with iisreset/stop from cmd prompt is this correct?

Comment: i stopped all services but still have the same error

Comment: Turns out i needed to uninstall Windows Process Activation Service